# JSF 2 dynamic ui:include reading old bean field value

Tags: jsf-2

I've been scratching my head, trying to think why this no longer works. I've got a page with a dynamic `<ui:include src="subpages/#{bean.subpage}.xhtml>`, along with some commandLinks that are supposed to set the value of the subpage bean field. The bean is a session-scoped Spring bean. All's well and good. But when clicking on a commandLink, I'm finding that the `<ui:include>` is reading the current value of the subpage field before my action, which sets the field's new value, is called. Given my current code below:

```
<h:form id="navform">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:commandLink value="Page 2" action="#{navigateTestBean.navigateToSection('page2')}"/>
        <h:commandLink value="Page 3" action="#{navigateTestBean.navigateToSection('page3')}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="mainArea">
    <ui:include src="subpages/#{navigateTestBean.sectionName}.xhtml"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and

```
@Service
@Scope("session")
public class NavigateTestBean {
    private String sectionName;

    @PostConstruct
    private void doSetup() {
        sectionName = "general";
    }

    public String navigateToSection(String sectionName) {
        this.sectionName = sectionName;
        return null;
    }

    public String getSectionName() {
        return sectionName;
    }

    public void setSectionName(String sectionName) {
        this.sectionName = sectionName;
    }
}
```

The first time I click a link, to say page2, getSectionName() is called, reads "general", and then navigateToSection() is called. No further getSectionName() is called, so ui:include ends up rendering the general subpage again. The next time I click a commandLink, whether the same or another one, I ultimately get page2 (the current value of sectionName before it's set to its new value) rendered.

I have also tried wrapping the commandLinks in `<f:ajax render=":mainArea">`, as noted in one of BalusC's other answers elsewhere, with no change in behavior.

What stupid little thing am I missing? Running on Tomcat 6.0.33 with the EL 2.2 parser, Mojarra 2.0.2 and RichFaces 4. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me . I am not using Spring so had to annotate it with '@managedbean' and '@seesionscope'. Also my EL version is different to what you have but non of this should matter.Are you using Webflow how is this a JSF managed bean. When I click page2 I get setion2 and when I click page3 I get section3.

Comment: Are you sure that 'getSectionName' is not getting called have you put the break point there. Looks okay to me other than the fact that it is a service which is very odd from design perspective but should not cause any issue.Can you provide little more detail about design and architecture of this application may bit more code. Depends on how much you need help you can post a zip file as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a bug in Mojarra 2.0.2. Upgraded to 2.1.3, the latest release in Maven, and the situation is resolved.